# Override PLIST file for iOS builds using VS2015 TACO to work around CB-10493 [iOS] Missing icon.png

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I am using VS2015 TACO to build a cordova application using Cordova 6.0 and Cordova-ios 4.0.1.

There is a registered issue CB-10493 [iOS] Missing icon.png 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10493

The work around for the issue requires you to update the PLIST file to remove a particular keyed entry from the PLIST file.  Unfortunately, because of the way that VS2015 TACO rebuilds the Cordova project on build, any manual edits to the files in the platforms folder is overwritten.

Directions on how to update the file was discussed here:
https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/configure-app/#VisualAssets

However upon putting the file in place, it seems to be ignored.  I copied the PLIST file in the platforms folder to: res/native/ios/myapp/myapp-Info.plist and removed the requisite entries.  I then removed the platforms folder and rebuilt the application.  This made no impact on the contents of the PLIST file in the platforms folder.

I could rollback versions for Cordova, however as this would involve also rolling back a number of plugins with fixes that I want to keep, I would prefer not to do this.

I would really appreciate if I could get clear working directions on how to implement an effective work-around to removing the offending entries from the PLIST file within a VS2015 TACO project.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Okay - discovered that despite the fact that the PLIST file in the platforms folder is not being overwritten, the use of a PLIST file in the native folder is still effective in working around the issue.

Discovered this when syntax errors entered my file and my build broke, despite the platforms copy of the PLIST still being exactly the same as the original.

Comment: When you say "the use of a PLIST file in the native folder is still effective in working around the issue" are you referring to the Cordova res/native folder?

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to the PLIST file in the Cordova res/native folder.  I expected this to be copied over to the platforms sub-folder when executing a build with VS2015 TACO.  Although the file doesn't seem to be copied over, the changes made to the PLIST file in the Cordova res/native folder does seem to be pushed to the Mac used for the build process on which cordova is executed.